# Compile errors with segment.io after Xcode 5.1 update

Tags: ios, xcode5.1

After updating to Xcode 5.1, receiving compile errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LocalyticsSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Analytics(LocalyticsProvider.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Segment.io posted a solution to this problem with update 0.10.1 - just add the new version of the Framework to your Xcode project: https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-ios/issues/98

Answer (score 0):

@snibbe, this seems to be still occurring using the [latest built SDK](https://s3.amazonaws.com/segmentio/releases/ios/Analytics-latest-stable.zip) (per the [manual installation instructions](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-ios/wiki/Installing-Manually)):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Localytics", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Analytics(SEGLocalyticsIntegration.o)
```

I've included all required frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Put this

```
libLocalyticsAMP_x64.a
```

instead of this in your frameworks

```
libLocalyticsAMP.a
```